# Fragmentation over the Transport layer (UDP)

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, network-protocols, transport-layer-protocol

A theoretical question.

How can Fragmentation be implemented over the transport layer in the OSI model?

How can I "change" the UDP protocol to support that thing?

Comment: Fragmentation of what? If it is about fragmentation of UDP payload you can model it similar to [how fragmentation works at the IP level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation), because basically UDP is just an unreliable message transport, similar to IP. And it is not about changing UDP: if you want to implement this you can do it inside UDP payloads without affecting the UDP protocol.

Comment: TCP and UDP do not fragment. IPv4 can fragment packets containing TCP or UDP. TCP segments a stream of data, so its datagrams are called segments, but that is completely different than fragmentation. UDP does not have segmentation, and it works best will a smaller payload because UDP has no guarantees, and you _will_ lose UDP datagrams, so the loss of a smaller datagram means you lose less data. The application or application-layer protocol must make sure that the data fit into the datagram, breaking up large data into smaller datagrams.

Comment: UDP has exactly nothing to do with [tag:osi], and neither does almost anything else.